# The <ui-select></ui-select> tag throws an error in browser

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, ui-select, angular-ui-select

The  tag is not being recognized in editor. I have included the script tags for angular select and bootstrap.

Comment: Consider adding more tags for better exposure and people who can answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error `Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller "ngModel", required by directive "uiSelectSingle"` tells you exactly what's wrong - you need to use `ng-model` to get the value out. For example:

`<ui-select ng-model="person.selected" theme="bootstrap">`